# WPF Context menu commands not setting IsEnabled properly

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to implement and use the WPF "[NotifyIcon](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon-2)" project.

I have installed the NuGet package in my project and have copied some files word-for-word while others implementing in my own way. I am, however, using .Net Core 3.0, instead of the .NetFramework it was originally designed for. I do think it supports .Net Core 3.0

The problem is that when I right-click the tray icon the "Show Command" and "Hide Command" menu items are not enabled or disabled properly, even when I test that their "CanExecute" methods return different values than what their "Enabled" property is, apparently, set to (this is to say, "Show Window" is enabled, but its "CanExecute" method returns `false`).

My changes are that instead of "DelegateCommand" I use the following "RelayCommand" class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace UserInterface
{
    class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        Action targetExecuteMethod;
        Func<bool> targetCanExecuteMethod;
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

        public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
        {
            targetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
            targetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            targetExecuteMethod?.Invoke();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (targetCanExecuteMethod != null)
                return targetCanExecuteMethod();

            if (targetExecuteMethod != null)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly my "NotifyIconViewModel" is thus:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace UserInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides bindable properties and commands for the NotifyIcon. In this sample, the
    /// view model is assigned to the NotifyIcon in XAML. Alternatively, the startup routing
    /// in App.xaml.cs could have created this view model, and assigned it to the NotifyIcon.
    /// </summary>
    public class NotifyIconViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Shows a window, if none is already open.
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ShowWindowCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand
                {
                    CanExecuteFunc = () => Application.Current.MainWindow == null,
                    CommandAction = () =>
                    {
                        Application.Current.MainWindow = new UserInterface.MainWindow();
                        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Hides the main window. This command is only enabled if a window is open.
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand HideWindowCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand
                {
                    CommandAction = () => Application.Current.MainWindow.Close(),
                    CanExecuteFunc = () => Application.Current.MainWindow != null
                };
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Shuts down the application.
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ExitApplicationCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand { CommandAction = () => Application.Current.Shutdown() };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

everything else is exactly as seen in the project's page. But just to be sure:

NotifyIconResources.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserInterface">

    <ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="SysTrayMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Show Window" Command="{Binding ShowWindowCommand}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Hide Window" Command="{Binding HideWindowCommand}"/>
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitApplicationCommand}"/>
    </ContextMenu>

    <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="NotifyIcon"
                        IconSource="/Icons/Bulb.ico"
                        ToolTipText="{Binding ToolTipText}"
                        DoubleClickCommand="{Binding ShowWindowCommand}"
                        ContextMenu="{StaticResource SysTrayMenu}">
        <tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
            <local:NotifyIconViewModel/>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in in the `EventHandler CanExecuteChanged`.

Mine does nothing, the `DelegateCommand` which the project uses originally does this:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

Using this `CanExecuteChanged` fixes things.
Can't tell you why it be like this, though.